# Getting rid of a superimposed image?

Tags: video

Is it possibile to cancel out an image superimposed on an another one if we know the overlaid image's alpha channel and pixel values?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're tying to remove a watermark from a copyrighted image.  The best way to do that is to pay the copyright owner for permission to use their image.